# TFS 2017 Namespace Does Not Exist

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am receiving this type of warning:

`##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1635,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "PatientEquipment".`(Should not be looking for the assembly on the C:\Drive.)

Shortly after, I am getting this error: 
`##[error]Full\Source Code\EA\DeviceApi\Controllers\Prescription.cs(18,31): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'BW' does not exist in the namespace 'PatientEquipment' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

I am in the process of moving builds from tfs 2013 to tfs 2017 and know that these builds have worked previously so there should not have to be any changes to the files, only to the build machine and in the tasks I create for the build. What ideas would you have for solving this error?

Comment: Can you build the project successfully with Visual Studio locally on the agent server ?  Seems you provided a absolute path for the referenced assemblies. Debug in VS first, then try using the Nuget to restore the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was missing .dll files which were pulled from another project and copied over to another project. On another project, I was having similar issues and just changed the version of Visual Studio that I was using in my tasks. It is interesting that the build needed 2017 instead of 2010 like it had been asking for in one of the csproj files.

Answer (score 2):

Open your project files in a text editor (could also open as XML file in Visual Studio) and search for PatientEquipment reference. It should have a HintPath. Make sure that this path is mapped in the build definition. Whether it is a file reference or a project reference, the path to that file (or project) seems to be missing in TFS build mapping

Answer (score 0):

Go to concerned DLL, do right click and change Specific version option to False. Build project once again. And try to check-in.

In this way we do not need to change anything in .csproj